# Inequality for matrix Frobenius norm: $\|A - B -C\|_F^2 \le \|A \|^2_F+ \|B\|_F^2 + \|C\|_F^2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

We know that

$$\|A + B\|_F \le \|A \|_F+ \|B\|_F$$

or

$$\|A \|_F- \|B\|_F \le \|A - B\|_F$$

Cn we prove the following?

$$\|A - B\|_F^2 \le \|A \|^2_F+ \|B\|_F^2$$

And for any matrix $A,B,C$

$$\|A - B -C\|_F^2 \le \|A \|^2_F+ \|B\|_F^2 + \|C\|_F^2$$

or

$$\|A - B + C\|_F^2 \le \|A \|^2_F+ \|B\|_F^2 + \|C\|_F^2$$

One more step: what if we want to remove the square just as

$$\|A - B -C\|_F \le \|A \|_F+ \|B\|_F + \|C\|_F$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Consider, e.g. $A=-B=I$ and $C=0$.

Comment: Thanks， You means $A = I, B = -I$ and $C = 0$ ?

Comment: @jason Yes. Then if the sizes of the matrices are $n\times n$, the LHS becomes $4n$ and the RHS becomes $2n$.

Comment: Thanks, how about this inequality $\|A - B -C\|_F \le \|A \|_F+ \|B\|_F + \|C\|_F $

Comment: @jason This one is true of course: it's just a repeated application of the triangle inequality.